# Get jSON data from URL using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am having difficulties retrieving data from API in a given URL `http://localhost:1337/api/volcano`.

The data that is captured from the API is in JSON format.
Now, how do I fetch and display in the browser the following array of data?

```
{"volcano":[{"id":12,"Name":"Krakatoa","Location":"AUSTRALIA","History":"The 1883 eruption of Krakatoa","Active":"dormant"}]}
```

**My Trials**

```
var settings = {
  "url": "http://localhost:1337/api/volcano",
  "method": "GET",
  "timeout": 0,
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  
  var data = $response;
});
```

display

```
<div id="data"></div>
```

Comment: Typo: `$response` needs to be `response` . Now that will only put the response into the var data. You still need to do something with it.

Comment: Can you explain why this question is tagged reactjs? I only see jQuery code...

Comment: check this tutorial: https://www.sitepoint.com/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple-example/

Comment: `function (response) { $('#data').html( JSON.stringify(response); ) }`